# What happens after 200 rep point cap is reached?

Tags: discussion, reputation, up-votes

Once you reach the daily reputation cap of 200, does the remaining balance of earned reputation apply to you the following day or is it ignored altogether?

EDIT: After reading Charles' answer, my question would be, why do we have this cap? Say someone is incredibly active on UX.stackexchange once or twice a week, answering multiple questions and giving good feedback, why would we penalize them for condensing their contributions into a constrained time period? What are the benefits of having this cap in the first place?

SECOND EDIT: I read this [What is the reasoning behind the reputation cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap) and now understand more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is gone. It wouldn't really be much of a cap if excess is carried over from day to day...

Comment: I thought it may have referred to a cap for the amount to be added in a day, with the remainder being added the next day, maybe as a holding period to prevent voter fraud or something. Like if someone got 500 in one day, one of the moderators would investigate it and make sure it's legit.

Comment: I think there should be better ways (as @MattRockwell suggests) for handling this.  Is the goal to discourage people from answering questions?  I doubt it.  Then it should fall to some level of flagging for moderators to check if there is a lot of voter fraud.  Not good game dynamics like this.